# Efficient way to optimise hyper parameter for network with multiple inputs?

Tags: keras, optimization, hyperparameter

I am currently looking for a way in which a network with multiple inputs can optimise its hyper parameter... scikit-learn has gridsearch CV but Keras only supports single inputs using the scikit-wrapper.

Any other way?

@Emre -  Minimal working example:

```
def train_generator():
    while True:
        train_input = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,33,8,45,3))
        train_input_list = np.split(train_input,33,axis=1)

        for i in range(len(train_input_list)):
            train_input_list[i] = train_input_list[i].reshape(1,8,45,3)

        train_output = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,3,50))
        yield (train_input_list, train_output)

def test_generator():
    while True:
        test_input = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,33,8,45,3))
        test_input_list = np.split(test_input,33,axis=1)

        for i in range(len(test_input_list)):
            test_input_list[i] = test_input_list[i].reshape(1,8,45,3)

        test_output = np.random.randint(100,size=(1,3,50))

        yield (test_input_list, test_output)

def data():
    X_train, Y_train = next(train_generator())
    X_test, Y_test = next(test_generator())

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    train_list = []
    for input in X_train:
        train_list.append(datagen.fit(input))

    return datagen, train_list, Y_train, X_test, Y_test

def fws(datagen, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test):
    #Input shape: (batch_size,40,45,3)
    #output shape: (1,15,50)
    # number of unit in conv_feature_map = splitd
    filter_size = 8
    pooling_size = 28
    stride_step = 2
    pool_splits = ((splits - pooling_size)+1)/2
    temp_list = []
    sun_temp_list = []
    conv_featur_map = []
    pool_feature_map = []
    print "Printing shapes"


    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (8,45,3)) for i in range(33)]


    #convolution
    shared_conv = Conv2D(filters = 150, kernel_size = (filter_size,45), activation='relu')
    for i in range(splits):
        conv_featur_map.append(shared_conv(list_of_input[i]))

    #Pooling
    input = Concatenate()(conv_featur_map)
    input = Reshape((splits,-1))(input)
    pooled = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = pooling_size, strides = stride_step)(input)

    #reshape = Reshape((3,-1))(pooled)

    #fc
    dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(pooled)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 50 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)


    model = Model(inputs = list_of_input , outputs = dense3)
    sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, decay = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, momentum = {{uniform(0, 1)}}, nesterov = True)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd , metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])
    #log= CSVLogger('/home/keerthikan/kaldi-trunk/dnn/original/training_total_frames_'+str(total_frames)+"_dim_"+str(dim)+"_window_height_"+str(window_height)+"_batch_"+str(batch)+"_lr_start_"+str(lr)+"_decay_"+str(decay)+"_mom_"+str(momentum)+"_fws.csv")
    #plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')


    hist_current = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train),
                        steps_per_epoch=32,
                        epochs = 1000,
                        verbose = 1,
                        validation_data = (X_test, Y_test),
                        validation_steps=32,
                        pickle_safe = True,
                        workers = 4)

    score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)

    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    datagen, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data()

    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=fws,
                                          data=data,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=5,
                                          trials=Trials())

    print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
    print(best_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))
```

And full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal_hyperas.py", line 167, in <module>
    trials=Trials())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 43, in minimize
    notebook_name=notebook_name, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 63, in base_minimizer
    model_str = get_hyperopt_model_string(model, data,functions,notebook_name, verbose, stack)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/optim.py", line 130, in get_hyperopt_model_string
    imports = extract_imports(cleaned_source, verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/utils.py", line 44, in extract_imports
    import_parser.visit(tree)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 249, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/utils.py", line 14, in visit_Import
    if (self._import_asnames(node.names)!=''):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperas/utils.py", line 36, in _import_asnames
    return ''.join(asname)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
```

Comment: http://maxpumperla.github.io/hyperas/

Comment: @Emre Doesn't seem to support multi input..

Comment: They provide an example with multiple hyperparameters (emphasis mine): "To do hyper-parameter optimization on this model, just wrap the **parameters** you want to optimize into double curly brackets and choose a distribution over which to run the algorithm. In the above example, let's say we want to optimize for the best dropout probability in **both** dropout layers."

Comment: @Emre multiple inputs as in the network takes in a list of input and spits out  one output.

Comment: What neural network doesn't accept multiple inputs? And what does that have to do with hyperparameter optimization? Even if you're confusing vector or structured features with recurrent neural networks, it still has nothing to do with hyperparameter optimization.

Comment: I tried hyperas with my network... I am not saying that it has anything to do with the hyperparameter optimization, but It does not seem like that hyperas is able to handle network with multiple inputs.  The program stalls with weird error messages. I've made an issue about it but no one has responded.  It seems to work fine with network having one input (and I guess one output) . It is not possible to pass the model through the  model.optimizer scheme in hyperas as the input dimension increases.

Comment: I guess the next step is to post your code (minimal working example), along with the error message.

Comment: @Emre added an  MVCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Differential Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution)?

It is similar to a genetic algorithm and appears to be available with [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html)

Comment: Interesting.. but how am I supposed to input my model, and how does it optimise? should i output value from the model or?

Comment: does it support use of multiple cores?